# Listening to Java custom event in MATLAB

Tags: java, events, matlab

The problem is as in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291769/how-do-i-notify-a-matlab-object-of-an-event-in-a-java-object).

I read the [example](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-callbacks-for-java-events/)  so many times already, but I still can't bring it to work.

The idea is to write an Event in Java and write a callback for MATLAB.

First I wrote my event class: package.EventTest.
Then I built it and in added the path with this classes to javaclasspath.

Then in matlab I execute:

```
evt = package.EventTest
set(evt,'TestEventCallback',@(h,e)disp(h))
evt.notifyMyTest
```

after line "evt.notifyMyTest" it should display something, but comes nothing.
I used a debugger and as it comes to function "notifyMyTest" I see that the vector with listeners is empty. So it can't show anything. What do I do wrong?
Does this line "set(evt,'TestEventCallback',@(h,e)disp(h))" have to add listener to this vector?

Or maybe there is another one possibility to challenge it?

Thanks in advance,
Lex

**UPD:** My Java class in package "package" ([example](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-callbacks-for-java-events/)):

```
public class EventTest {

    private java.util.Vector data = new java.util.Vector();
    public synchronized void addMyTestListener(MyTestListener lis) {
        data.addElement(lis);
    }
    public synchronized void removeMyTestListener(MyTestListener lis) {
        data.removeElement(lis);
    }
    public interface MyTestListener extends java.util.EventListener {
        void testEvent(MyTestEvent event);
    }
    public class MyTestEvent extends java.util.EventObject {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public float oldValue,newValue;        
        MyTestEvent(Object obj, float oldValue, float newValue) {
            super(obj);
            this.oldValue = oldValue;
            this.newValue = newValue;
        }
    }
    public void notifyMyTest() {
        java.util.Vector dataCopy;
        synchronized(this) {
            dataCopy = (java.util.Vector)data.clone();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<dataCopy.size(); i++) {
            MyTestEvent event = new MyTestEvent(this, 0, 1);
        ((MyTestListener)dataCopy.elementAt(i)).testEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to call MATLAB code from Java? is "package.EventTest" a MATLAB class or a Java class? Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I found another way to do what I want.
Now I use `PropertyChangeSupport` and `PropertzChangeListener`.

In Matlab I add

> 'PropertyChangeCallback'

Then from Java-code I send

> firePropertyChange("Property", oldValue, newValue)

And my Matlab code is notified.

Looks like it's working

Comment: Hi Lex, do you think you could expand on your solution? I've run into problems with the same EventTest class from Undocumented Matlab, and I'm hoping your solution will work for me. What did you add in Matlab? Where did you add that code in Java?